# Stuck with a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I must call a function to translate French phrases to English and I'm stuck on the `showEnglish()`. It will not pull the `english` arrays. And I'm not even sure if I'm referencing the setup function right which I had in a separate JavaScript file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
window.onload = setup;
function setup() {   
    var questions = document.querySelectorAll("article ol li");
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        questions[i].id = i + "phrase"; 
        questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish;
        //questions[i].onmouseup = showFrench;
        questions[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
    }    
}
function showEnglish() {  
    var phrases = document.getElementById("phrase");
    var phraseNumber = parseInt(phrases.id);
    phraseNumber.innerHTML = english[phraseNumber];
    phraseNumber.style.fontStyle = "italic";
    phraseNumber.style.fontColor = "rgb(191, 22, 31)";
 }
```

Comment: `phraseNumber` contains a numeric value after you assign the result of `parseInt()`.  So why are you later treating it like it is a DOM element, by setting properties on it such as `innerHTML`, `style`, etc?  That won't work the way you're expecting.

Comment: I think this is where I am getting confused. Thanks! I'll gon back and correct it!

Comment: `MouseDown` event is passed as a param of  `showEnglish` function when called. You must use `event.srcElement` (or `event.target` on Firefox) to retrieve the element that fired the event and its `id`. But can can simplify this and avoid use of ids. See my answer below.

Comment: So did it worked ? Any feedback would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample snippet which does not use ids and should match your needs.

> Questions list can easily be built from translations object using a script. (Check snippet in **second solution** below)

```js
// On document load (warning: does not work with IE8)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setup()
})

// Store French -> English translations
var translations = {
  "Comment vous appelez vous ?": "What's your name ?",
  "Où habitez vous ?": "Where do you live ?"
};

// Attach `translate` function to questions `mousedown` event
function setup() {   

     document
     .querySelectorAll("article ol li")
     .forEach(function(el) {
       el.onmousedown = showEnglish
     });
}

// Display translation when mousedown on element
function showEnglish(event) {
    var element = event.srcElement || event.target
    var translation = document.getElementById("translation");
    translation.innerHTML = translations[element.innerText];
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .question { cursor: pointer; padding: 4px }
  .translation { font-style: italic; color: rgb(191, 22, 31) }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Questions</h3>
  <article>
    <ol>
      <li class="question">Comment vous appelez vous ?</li>
      <li class="question">Où habitez vous ?</li>
    </ol>
  </article> 
  <h3>Traduction</h3>
  <div class="translation" id="translation"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Other solution**

Build DOM from translations

```js
// On document load (warning: does not work with IE8)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    buildDOM();
})

// Store French -> English translations
var translations = {
    "Comment vous appelez vous ?": "What's your name ?",
    "Où habitez vous ?": "Where do you live ?"
};

// Display translation when mousedown on element
function showEnglish(event) {
    var element = event.srcElement || event.target
    var translation = document.getElementById("translation");
    translation.innerHTML = translations[element.innerText];
}

function buildDOM() {
    var ol = document.createElement("ol");

    for (var t in translations) {
        var el = document.createElement("li");
        el.className = "question";
        el.innerText = t;
        el.onmousedown = showEnglish
        ol.appendChild(el);
    }

    document.getElementById("questions").appendChild(ol);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .question { cursor: pointer; padding: 4px }
        .translation { font-style: italic; color: rgb(191, 22, 31) }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Questions</h3>
  <div id="questions"></div>
  <h3>Traduction</h3>
  <div id="translation" class="translation"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a second solution